# DAX filter function SSMS

Tags: filtering, dax

Writing DAX in SSMS. Need to bring all rows and columns from my table (DimProduct),
should be filtered on another table (subcategory) and only show SubcategoryKey nr 19
This is my code:

```
EVALUATE 'Produkt'
(
    Filter
    (
        'DimProductSubcategory',

'DimProductSubcategory'[ProductSubcategoryKey]=19
))
```

I get this error however:
"The function used in this expression is not a valid function nor the name of a measure."

How should it be written?

Answer (score 0):

First option:

```
EVALUATE
FILTER (
    'DimProductSubcategory',
    'DimProductSubcategory'[ProductSubcategoryKey] = 19
)
```

Second option:

```
DEFINE
    VAR T =
        FILTER (
            'DimProductSubcategory',
            'DimProductSubcategory'[ProductSubcategoryKey] = 19
        )
EVALUATE T
```

PS:

[I recommend this website for the DAX query formatting :)](http://www.daxformatter.com/)

PS2:

[New SSMS introduces DAX Query Editor which is essentially intellisense for DAX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2017/03/14/ssms-dax-query-editor/)